# Reselect selector params are being called on every state change

Tags: react-redux, reselect

My state is for simplicity

```
export default combineReducers({
    combinedReducer1,
    combinedReducer2,
});
```

and i have a mapStateToProps as follows:

```
 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    reducer1: testReselect(state)
});
```

where testReselect is

```
const testReselect = createSelector(
    state => state,
    state => state
);
```

and i see that the reselect is being called on every nested change in combinedReducer1. Shouldn't rootState reference be the same on any nested state change? If not is there any point using reselect?

Comment: If any nested value is re created then so is it's parent. in `newState = {...parent, child: {...parent.child, grandChild:{...parent.child.grandChild, newValue}}}` newState is re created, so is newState.parent, newState.parent.child and newState.parent.child.grandChild. Your selector should select only the values that are needed by the component and thus not re render the component if no relevant state values change. If your component shows the entire state then it should re render when anything in the state changes.

Comment: Thank you @HMR. So in case i am sending the root state, the selector will be called on any nested change, which means always. Correct? So it actually loses the purpose of the reselect

Comment: Although it makes sense. Otherwise it would be triggered.

Comment: If an action causes a new state to be created then all the callbacks passed to `useSelector` will be called, if a different value is returned then the component will re create jsx. So if your selector callback returns the root state then the component will re create jsx. React will compare current jsx with the last created one and re render DOM if they are different.